# Dynamic Embedded Twitter Widgets

Tags: twitter

Is there an automated way to generate twitter widgets? I have a few hundred separate timelines that I'd like to create widgets for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this, it's exceptionally simple.

http://tomsbigbox.com/create-a-dynamic-twitter-search-feed/